# node.js response.writeHead on http module

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm implementing my own http module. 
As I'm reading the official node.js http module api, I couldn't understand a few things:

1. If the user is using the `response.writeHead(statusCode, [reasonPhrase], [headers])` function, are the headers should be written immidiatly to the socket or are they first supposed to be saved as a member to the object? and then written only after `.end()` function?
2. What is the meaning of implicit headers that should be used whenever the user didn't use `writeHead()`? are they supposed to be set ahead? and if the user didn't set them? what should be the behavior? thanks

Comment: So actually I found an answer for the first question, so I have only left the second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers:

1. Anything that you write into response either headers with `writeHead` or body with `write` is buffered and sent. You see they use socket buffers. They can only hold fixed amount of data, before being sent. The important fact to remember is that you can only set headers before you start writing the body. If you do, some headers will set for you by the http server itself.
2. Implicit headers are ones which you don't write specifically but are still sent. Setup a simple http server, by responding a request without setting any header. Then view the request headers opening the site in browser. There will be headers like Date, Server, Host etc which are added to every request automatically without user's volition.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for the first question, but still don't understand the second one.

```
The first time response.write() is called, it will send the buffered header information and the first body to the client. The second time response.write() is called, Node assumes you're going to be streaming data, and sends that separately. That is, the response is buffered up to the first chunk of body.
```